# C multithreaded application structs

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I'm trying to write multithread application, which will share some parameters through structs. Here are relevant parts of code.

```
typedef struct {
    ....
    char xml_file[1024];
    ....
} GeneratorData;
```

In main thread (function)

```
GeneratorData generator_data;
ConnectionData connection_data;

bzero(&connection_data, sizeof(connection_data));
bzero(&generator_data, sizeof(generator_data));

strcpy(generator_data->xml_file, argv[1]);
strcpy(connection->xml_file, argv[1]);

if(pthread_create(&generate, NULL, (void*)Generator__Init, (void *)&generator_data) < 0){
      return -1;
}

if(pthread_create(&connection, NULL, (void*)Connection__Connect, (void *)&connection_data) < 0){
      return -1;
}
pthread_join(generate, NULL);
```

The issue is, that sometimes (much often) content of xml_file in Generator__Init function is not, what I set into it.

In function Generator_*Init is everything OK until Connection*_Connect function starts. What would be the problem here ? Into the thread connection I didn't get variables from struct generator.

Thank you for advice

Comment: If your threads manipulate the structure, an synchronous access may lead to weird data

Answer (score 0):

Your data is shared between the treads. So if one is manipulating data it is changing what is visible for the other. You'd have to learn more about thread programming in general and POSIX threads in particular.

Also:

- `bzero` is deprecated since long, use `memset`
- if you need casts for your thread function you are most certainly doing something wrong. These are supposed to be function pointers with the correct prototype, not data pointers.
- have your program compile without casts and with all warning levels turned on. the compiler is your friend.

Comment: I'm not sure, if data are shared. I make a string copy of input parameters into struct and don't share these structs between threads (there isn't any pointer from generator thread to connection struct, same in other way).

Solving casts didn't solve my problem.